# Poner un checkbox en checked si el valor es True en Angular 7

Tags: mysql, angular, mvc, typescript, checkbox

Buen dia

Requiero su ayuda ya que necesito que los checkbox de mi select multi opcion de Angular material que reciban el valor "true" de la base de datos, automaticamente se pongan con palomita o "checked".

Como puedo lograr esto?

Codigo HTML

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="foros">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="text-align: center;align-items: center">Foros</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Foros</mat-label>
              <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let dato of element.optionsForos" [value]="dato.val">{{dato.label}}</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field></td>
          </ng-container>
```

Codigo TS

```
public transfromData(datos: Array<any>){

    return datos.map(dato => {

      dato["optionsForos"] = [
        {
          val: dato.autoevaluacion,
          label: "Autoevaluacion"
        },
        {
          val: dato.rt_funcionarios,
          label: "RT_Funcionarios"
        },
        {
          val: dato.reporteadores,
          label: "Reporteadores"
        },
        {
          val: dato.reporteadores_gerentes,
          label: "Reporteadores_Gerentes"
        },
        {
          val: dato.rt_gerentes,
          label: "RT_Gerentes"
        },
        {
          val: dato.contrato_funcionarios,
          label: "Contratos_Funcionarios"
        },
        {
          val: dato.rt_jefes,
          label: "RT_Jefes"
        },
        {
          val: dato.contrato_gerentes,
          label: "Contrato_Gerentes"
        },
      ]   ;

      console.log(dato)

      return dato;

    });

  }

  public async obtenerUsuarios(){
    let data;
    this.tablaUsuarios = await this.forosServicio.getUsuarios(data);
    console.log(this.tablaUsuarios)
    this.tablaUsuarios = this.transfromData(this.tablaUsuarios);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.tablaUsuarios);
    console.log(this.dataSource)

  }
```

Actualmente el select luce asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero que quisiera de que de recibir la combinacion [true,true,false,false,false,false,true,true], se viera automaticamente asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]